# If any textbox on page is changed, call function

Tags: javascript

I know how to check if *one* textbox is changed, but what about if *any* textbox is changed?
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: tried using jquery for that ?

Comment: @Brian and where is the event functionality in that ?

Comment: that would be in the foreach loop.   where is the functionality in "tried using jquery"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$("input[type=text]").change(function() {

    // put your code here

});
```

EDIT:

If you are new to [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or don't know about it, it's a JavaScript framework. Click [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to learn about it's `change()` function.

Comment: does .change() also recognize if you are inserting text via right-click ?

Comment: @EvilP i believe so. I just tested it here and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/uBqx7/

Comment: Since OP did not mention jQuery or tag with jQuery, you should at least provide a link to the jQuery site, and hopefully provide a non-jQuery answer.

Comment: @Raynos Not true. jQuery is JavaScript. The OP didn't post any code that they've tried and was fishing for ideas.  This is one. Thanks for the downvote though.

Answer (score 3):

the following code will append onchange event listeners to all input tags on the page with type equal to "text".

```
var textboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
    if(textboxes[i].type == "text") {
        textboxes[i].onchange = function() {alert("changed");};
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `onchange` rather than `onclick`, because `onclick` would alert *before* any change was made, and wouldn't check to see if a change *was* made following the click event.

Comment: sry, my mistake; I accidently wrote onclick

Comment: and about jquery..;for me, personally, it takes all fun out of javascript

Comment: In the line textboxes[i].type.onchange = .... there should be no "type". In other words, it should be textboxes[i].onchange = ...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you have all your textboxes in one div. Use [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html):

```
// Add an event handler on your whole div
document.getElementById('div-with-your-checkboxes').onchange = function(e) {
    // Cross browser check
    var evt = e || window.event
    // Get the element that triggered the event
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement
    // Check if it is an INPUT element
    if (target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
        // Your code in here.
    }
}
```

This way, you add only one event which will check every `onchange` events in your div. Just a simple check and you're done.

This is way more efficient than adding an event handler for every `input` element.

PS: the jQuery way would be like this:

```
$('#div-with-your-checkboxes').change(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).tagName === 'INPUT') {
        // Your code in here.
    }
})
```

As you can see, jQuery is not really needed for this simple task :-).

Comment: Just for the sake of example, common! But I edited for your sake :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use some jQuery.

Give the textbox's a class, e.g. `class="onchange"` then add some jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $('.onchange').change(function(){
      // your code in here.
   });
});
```

That way, any textbox with the class `onchange` will raise the jQuery `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `document.getElemenetsByTagName("input")`.  For each element, verify that type == "text" and, if so, attach an event listener.

JQuery does this in a line: `$("input[type=text]").on("change", function() { ... })`

If you want to do this for text boxes created dynamically after load time, use `$("input[type=text]").live("change", function() { ... })`